# Clean code: Permission with middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my example, I have four models: User, Company, Project, and Plant (though my project technically has more: Plant, Job, Team, etc.).

```
Model User: name, role, company: { id, role }, projects: [ { id, role } ], plants: [ { id, role } ]
Model Company: name, members [ ], projects [ ]
Model Project: title, members [ ], company, plants [ ]
Model Plant: title, members [ ], project, jobs [ ]
```

First, I wrote a simple script to check the role of a given user (middleware.js):

```
const isAdmin = (user) => {
    return user.role === "admin"
}

const isCompanyMember = (user, companyId) => {
    return user.company.id && user.company.id.equals(companyId)
}
```

To check multiple permissions, I wrote a function that always gets used in the middleware.

```
const checkPermit = (...checks) => {
    let permit = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
        if (checks[i]) permit = 1
    }
    return permit
}
```

Afterwards, I wrote this function to get a list of users by project ID (controller.js):

```
const getListUsersByProjectId = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { projectId } = req.params
    try {
        const project = await Project.findById(projectId)
            .select("members")
            .populate("members", "name")
        if (!project) return next("Project not found")
        res.json({
            result: 'ok',
            message: "Find list of users successfully",
            data: project
        })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

To more easily find a given project by its ID, I wrote this helper function:

```
const findProject = (projectId) => {
    return Project.findById(projectId)
}
```

Finally, I wrote the router (router.js):

```
router.get('/get-list-users/:projectId',
    authentication.required,
    // I set signed user to req.user in function authentication.required
    async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            let { user } = req
            let project = await findProject(req.params.projectId)
            if (!project) return next("Can not find project")
            let permit = checkPermit(
                isAdmin(user)
                isCompanyMember(user, project.company)
            )
            if (permit) return next()
            else return next("You don't have authorization to do this action!")
        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    },
    getListUsersByProjectId
)
```

It's working well and as intended, but the code isn't particularly fun to work with! How can I improve the code and make it more clean?